# Adding a column in pandas df using a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I have a Pandas df [see below].
How do I add values from a function to a new column "price"?

function:

```
def getquotetoday(symbol):
    yahoo = Share(symbol)
    return yahoo.get_prev_close()
```

df:

```
Symbol      Bid     Ask
MSFT      10.25   11.15
AAPL     100.01  102.54
...
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In general, you can use the apply function. If your function requires only one column, you can use:

```
df['price'] = df['Symbol'].apply(getquotetoday)
```

as @EdChum suggested. If your function requires multiple columns, you can use something like:

```
df['new_column_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_function(x['value_1'], x['value_2']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.pipe.html):

```
df['price'] = df['Symbol'].pipe(getquotetoday)
```

Comment: This assumes `Share` works on a Series. Is that reasonable? I'm not familiar with whatever library OP's using. If it is, why bother when you could just do `df['price'] = getquotetoday(df['Symbol'])`? If it isn't, maybe you're thinking of [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)?