# function to join strings and some values from columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with columns and rows. Now I want to create another column which will be a concatenation of two strings and a column from the dataframe.
so the way it would work is i have string one (see the below dictionary)+ colx (from dataframe) + string two

```
stringList = {
     'one': """ AC:A000 AMI:NO CM:B C:YES CL:CPN:'#US3L+""",
     'two': """ FRQ:4  NOT:1 PX:C PXND:1E-6:DOWN RDTE:MAT RP:1 SET:0WW XD:NO """
}
```

i tried to create a function but I think this is not working as I want. I want this to be a function so i can call it in another function.

```
def fun(final):

    for i in dm:
        c = stringList['one'] + str(dm[i]) + stringList['two']
        final.append(c)
```

Please help with this as I am stuck with this problem for now.

Required Output:

```
str1                                      |QM     |str2          |output
 AC:A000 AMI:NO CM:B C:YES CL:CPN:'#US3L+ |0.0125 | RQ:4  NOT:1 PX:C PXND:1E-6:DOWN RDTE:MAT RP:1 SET:0WW XD:NO|    AC:A000 AMI:NO CM:B C:YES CL:CPN:'#US3L+0.0125RQ:4  NOT:1 PX:C PXND:1E-6:DOWN RDTE:MAT RP:1 SET:0WW XD:NO
```

AC:A000 AMI:NO CM:B C:YES CL:CPN:'#US3L+    0.016   RQ:4  NOT:1 PX:C PXND:1E-

Hope this helps explain. I know it is not a very good representation but I have this problem which is critical to solve
THanks

Comment: What is the output you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: There's no such thing as a python dataframe. Are we talking pandas here?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have edited the question to include output

Comment: @mypetlion my bad. meant to say pandas

Comment: Can you add `dm` and how you are calling `fun`? Also loops over dataframes are bad. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40045819/2308683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your output, I realized that you want to combine three columns `str1`, `QM`, and `str2`. I am assuming here that `str1` and `str2` have dtype str and `QM` has dtype float. You can use the following code to get the `output` column as below

`df["output"] = df["str1"] + df["QM"].astype(str) +  df["str2"]`