# Pandas: How to extract and calculate the number of “hour” per row in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, feature-engineering

I have a data frame representing the schedule of some restaurants in a week.

- **What i want to do is to add a column `week_hours` to my initial Dataframe `df` that represents the total number of hours the restaurant is open per week.**

**note** : the value 0 simply means that the restaurant is closed that day.

```py
data = {
        'restaurant_id':  ['1', '2','3'],
        'Monday':  ['11:0-20:0', '11:30-22:0','11:30-21:0'],
        'Tuesday':  ['11:0-20:0', '11:30-22:0','11:30-22:0'],
        'Wednesday':  ['11:0-20:0', '11:30-22:0','11:30-21:0'],
        'Thursday':  ['11:0-20:0', '11:30-22:0','11:30-21:0'],
        'Friday':  ['11:0-22:0', '11:30-22:0','11:30-21:0'],
        'Saturday':  ['11:0-22:0', '12:0-22:0','0'],
        'Sunday':  ['11:0-17:0', '16:30-21:30','11:30-21:0',],

        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['restaurant_id','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday',])
df.head()
```

What could be a simple syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to first `transpose` and then create custom function to `extract` the values before calculation (note that this works only if the hours doesn't go pass 24, else need `Timedelta`):

```
def find_diff(col):
    data = col.str.extract(r"(\d*):(\d*)-(\d*):(\d*)").astype(float)
    hours = (data[2] - data[0]).sum()
    minutes = (data[3] - data[1]).sum()/60
    return hours+minutes

print (df.set_index("restaurant_id").T.apply(find_diff)) 

restaurant_id
1    64.0
2    67.5
3    58.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: how can i add those results in a column inside my df?

Comment: `df["new"] = df.set_index("restaurant_id").T.apply(find_diff).to_numpy()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply`, see this answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/40045819/14273548.

```
def calc_hours(ranges):
    # calc the hours in the ranges and sum

df['Weekly Hours'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum(calc_hours(x[day]) for day in ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']), axis=1)
```